# Inserting data to a Room database

Tags: android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, android-design-library, android-developer-api

When it comes to inserting data on a RoomDB, what is the best method to handle the conflict strategy?
As i have tried.

```
@Insert(onConflict = @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE))
```

But it didn't work, as during conflict it sometimes duplicates and mess the auto increment on the plk values.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.NONE)
```

But that sometimes does not replace, hence at sometimes I had to go back to use the first conflict strategy `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)`

The documentation is giving me two statements for the same function or library `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)`
When you whover your mouse on "REPLACE" it says *"OnConflict strategy constant to replace the old data and continue the transaction"* on `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` where on `OnConflictStrategy.NONE` you get *"OnConflict strategy constant used by default when no other strategy is set. Using it prevents Room from generating ON CONFLICT clause. It may be useful when there is a need to use ON CONFLICT clause within a trigger. The runtime behavior is the same as when ABORT strategy is applied. The transaction is rolled back"*

But when you navigate to the implemantation or library object. you get something like *"OnConflict strategy constant to rollback the transaction."* on `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` where on `OnConflictStrategy.NONE` you get *"OnConflict strategy constant to replace the old data and continue the transaction."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mess the auto increment on the plk values

The intended use of a rowid, which a column with AUTOINCREMENT is an alias of, is to uniquely **id**entify a **row**. If you are using the value in another way then you may well have issues.

The option that you appear to have dismissed is `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)`. This will ignore the conflict and be reflected by the Long value returned by the `@Insert` returning -1 (instead of the generated value).

As such if you want to do an insert or replace without the potential issues with `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` then you could either

use an **[@Upsert](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Upsert)**

or use code that ignores the conflict such as :-

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(whatever: WHATEVERCLASS): Long
@Update
fun update(whatever: WHATEVERCLASS): Int

@Transaction
@Query("")
@InsertOrUpdate(whatever: WHATEVECLASS)
    if (insert(whatever) < 1) {
        update(whatever)
    }   
}
```

- NOTE in both circumstances reliance is made upon the primary key identifying the row to be updated.
- if there are other constraints that result in a trappable conflict then the solution would be more complex.

Comment: Thank you @MikeT for responding to my problem. But ```@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)``` It always cause duplicates when I try to do reports on the data I have on my Room, because I use Room just to store data incase I don't have connection to internet. Then when I get internet back, that's when I push data to my remote server, but then when i trace the records from the remote server I see lots of duplicates